# Rxjs Subject unexpected single value emitted

Tags: rxjs

In Angular 2+ I'm setting up a [`CanActivate`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) guard.

The code below emulates its behavior where the inner `of(true).pipe(delay(5000))` emulates a API call that should tell if the user is authenticated and able to access the guarded components.

```js
import { BehaviorSubject, of, switchMap, delay, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

class MyGuard implements CanActivate {
  readonly auth$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

  canActivate() {
    return auth$.pipe(switchMap((val) => {
      if (!val) {
        return of(true)
          .pipe(delay(5000)
          .pipe(tap(() => {
            subj.next(true);
          });
      }

      return of(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine but, what I can't understand is why if `val` is `false` I only get one result in `subscribe` while I was expecting the one from the inner `Observable` (i.e.: the result value of `of(true)`) ***AND*** the one emitted when I called `next(true)`.

To better clarify, I was expecting two values when I do this:

```js
const guard = new MyGuard();
guard.canActivate().subscribe((val) => {
  console.log(val); // only one value logged
});
```

Any explanation is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a great example which illustrate the difference between `switchMap` and `concatMap`/`mergeMap`.

When you use `switchMap` and a new value gets emitted by the outer observable, the inner observable will be cancelled.

This does not happend with `mergeMap` which handle the inner observables concurently, while `concat` will wait for the previous inner observable to be finished to send the next one.